# Mule test code for inbound file polling

Tags: testing, mule

I'm new to Mule ESB.

I have the following config file for Mule which was taken from the Spell Checker tutorial:

```
<file:connector name="FILE" streaming="false" doc:name="File" autoDelete="true" validateConnections="false"/>
<flow name="SpellCheckerFlow1" doc:name="SpellCheckerFlow1">        
    <file:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="FILE" path=".\xmlIn" pollingFrequency="3000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Incoming File" moveToDirectory=".\xmlProcessed"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?lang=en" port="80" doc:name="Invoke API"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path=".\xmlOut" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].xml" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```

I'm trying to extend the `FunctionalTestCase` class and test this flow. Below is the extracted code I'm using to do that:

```
MuleClient client = new MuleClient(muleContext);        
client.dispatch("file://./xmlIn", "<valid_xml />", null);
MuleMessage message = client.request("file://./xmlOut", 1000000000);
```

When I execute this code it creates a data file in the /xmlIn folder. The rest of the flow does not get executed. The flow should poll on this folder to pick up the file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time-out parameter is ineffective when requesting from a `file` endpoint: Mule is not going to wait for the file to appear.

This means that your test doesn't block and always fails. The easiest/less refined way to solve the issue is to loop on a `{ Thread.wait(); client.request(); }` until you get a non-null `message`, ie until the file in `xmlOut` has been read.

No need to add a retry counter: Mule's `FunctionalTestCase` will automatically fail the test after `getTestTimeoutSecs()` has elapsed (60 seconds by default).

Side notes:

- To make your config work in my environment, I had to replace the `.\` with `./` in the file paths of the XML config.
- The outbound HTTP endpoint is mis-configured: the `path` is mixed in the `host`, use instead:

  ```
  <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
      host="www.google.com" path="tbproxy/spell?lang=en" port="80"
      doc:name="Invoke API" />
  ```
- It's slightly more efficient to get the Mule client this way:

  ```
  MuleClient muleClient = muleContext.getClient();
  ```

Comment: Thanks David. Like you said the issue was with my test case. It timed out before the flow executed. I added a delay on my test case and it worked fine. Thanks for the recomendations as well. They make sense.